# Azure runbook Cmdlet missing

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, azure-runbook

I am trying to run following cmdlet- Set-UnifiedGroup 
 but it is not available in  [ExchangePowerShell 0.11.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ExchangePowerShell/0.11.0)
Is there a way to import it to Automation Account module in different way?
If this cmdldet is not available, any tip on changing group email from Azure Automation?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-exo-powershell-managed-identity?view=exchange-ps), you may try to depend on microsoft graph or else try to connect using msonline and then use set-unifiedgroup approach directly.